# Catch url with catch all re not rendering css

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

I'm building an app on the webapp2 framework in Google App Engine in Python.  I've been using Jinja2 as my template engine and Twitter Bootstrap for styling purposes.  After building a nice "layout.html" and having all other templates inherit from the "layout.html", I deployed.  All pages render property, except one, the one whose url is dynamic.

Here is what the WSGI handler looks like:

```
webapp2.WSGIApplication = ([('/login', LoginPage),
                           ('/updates', Update),
                           ('/updates/.*', Individual)],
                           debug = True)

# as you can see I'm using the catchall regex for Individual
```

Functionally, each dynamically generated url handled by **Individual** operates properly.  Here is the handler, again, everything within this handler is getting executed.

```
class Individual(Handler):
    def get(self):
            url_u = str(self.request.url)
            posit = url_u.find('updates')
            bus1 = url_u[posit+8:]
            bus = bus1.replace('%20', chr(32))
            b = BusUpdates.all()
            this_bus = b.order('-timestamp').filter('bus = ', bus).fetch(limit=10)
            name = users.get_current_user()
            user = None
            if name:
                    user = name.nickname()
            logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)

            self.render("individual.html", bus=bus, user=user, this_bus=this_bus, logout=logout)
```

A typical url will look like:
     http://www.megabusfinder.appspot.com/updates/St%20Louis,%20MO-Chicago,%20IL-4-12-930AM-310PM

Here is my app.yaml file

```
application: megabusfinder
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no


handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico


- url: /static/stylesheets
  static_dir: static/stylesheets


- url: /twitter-bootstrap-37d0a30
  static_dir: twitter-bootstrap-37d0a30


- url: /static/xml
  static_dir: static/xml

- url: .*
  script: main.app


builtins:
- remote_api: on


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Now, I previously had the "individual.html" inheriting from my "layout.html".  As of about an hour ago, I no longer am doing that and I've manually added all the necessary bootstrap that I use in "layout.html" to "individual.html".  Even with this, no styling is in effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked that you can manually download the css?
if not check your app.yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are using relative URL paths for your stylesheets, rather than absolute paths.  You are doing this:

```
<link href="styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When you should be doing this:

```
<link href="/styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The issue is that the browser will make a request for a relative URL like that one by combining the existing URL with the relative URL provided in your `href` (or `src` for a JavaScript file).

On your *root* pages the browser makes a request for megabusfinder.appspot.com/styles/bootstrap.css.  On your non-root pages it makes a request for megabusfinder.appspot.com/some/sub/path + styles/bootstrap.css ... which doesn't exist, resulting in a 404 (and an unstyled page).

Providing a leading slash ensures that the browser will *replace* the current path with the `href` path, rather than combining the paths.

See [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more information on how URIs are merged.

Comment: It's the little syntactical errors that always get me.  I really appreciate the response.  That worked.  You've also taught me a little more about relative and absolute paths, something I knew was important, but haven't read a whole lot about.  Thanks again.